# How can I tell my Mac not to search for my bluetooth speakers when I'm on the go?

Tags: macos, macbook, bluetooth, connection

I'm using a MacBook Pro (early 2010) and I have Jawbone speakers.

When I'm using other bluetooth devices (e.g. the Mighty Mouse) in a place where my speakers aren't, I have turned the bluetooth off for the speakers. Still my laptop tries to connect to the speakers every two minutes saying "Can't find the speakers".

Do I have to delete my Jawbone speakers from the Bluetooth Preferences every time I'm using my laptop in a place where my speakers are not?

Comment: It might be an issue with the speakers itself, so I'd try asking in the [Jawbone forums](http://forums.jawbone.com/jawbone/) too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Apple Logo** → **System Preferences** → **Sound** → **Output** → **Internal Speakers**. That should fix it.

If not, click the Bluetooth menu bar icon, then select your speakers in the drop-down menu and click disconnect. When you want to reconnect, just do the same thing, but click connect instead.